# Mock 2 clocks for different integration in same class - Micronaut

Tags: java, testing, integration-testing, micronaut

I'm facing an issue in my Micronaut integration test where I'm trying to use two different fixed clocks in two separate tests. One should be set to 10th Oct 1800, and the other to 10th Oct 1900. However, my current approach doesn't seem to work. Below is a simplified version of my code:

This is my code:

```java
package some.package.path;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.*;

import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Property;
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Requires;
import io.micronaut.test.annotation.MockBean;
import io.micronaut.test.extensions.junit5.annotation.MicronautTest;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import java.time.Clock;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

@MicronautTest(rebuildContext = true)
class AzureTest {
  @Inject Clock clock;

  @MockBean(Clock.class)
  @Requires(missingProperty = "mock.clock")
  Clock fixed() {
    return Clock.fixed(
        LocalDate.of(1800, 10, 10).atStartOfDay().toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC), ZoneOffset.UTC);
  }

  @MockBean(Clock.class)
  @Requires(property = "mock.clock", value = "true")
  Clock fixed2() {
    return Clock.fixed(
        LocalDate.of(1900, 10, 10).atStartOfDay().toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC), ZoneOffset.UTC);
  }

  @Test
  void testItWorks() {
    Instant instant = clock.instant();
    LocalDate date = instant.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDate();
    System.out.println("======" + date + "======");
    assertThat(date).isEqualTo(LocalDate.of(1800, 10, 10));
  }

  @Test
  @Property(name = "mock.clock", value = "true")
  void testItWorks2() {
    Instant instant = clock.instant();
    LocalDate date = instant.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDate();
    System.out.println("======" + date + "======");
    assertThat(date).isEqualTo(LocalDate.of(1900, 10, 10));
  }
}
```

How can I achieve this within the same file without resorting to splitting the tests into different files? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

#### What I tried

I tried using a service

```java
interface MyService {
    Clock getDate();
}

@Singleton
@Requires(missingProperty = "foo.bar")
static class MyServiceStuff implements MyService {
  @Override
  public Clock getDate() {
     // 10th Oct 1800    
  }
}

@Singleton
@Requires(property = "foo.bar", value = "changed")
static class MyServiceChanged implements MyService {
  @Override
  public Clock getDate() {
    // 10th Oct 1900    
  }
}
```

But this is only helpful, if I want to create or get date using MyService.
Example:

```java
@Inject MyService myservice;

@Property(name = "foo.bar", value = "changed")
some_test {
   myservice.getDate();
}
```

Once my code transitions from the controller to the service layer, the service utilizes `LocalDate.now(clock)`. During this phase, a static clock is required. Consequently, the previously suggested solution becomes ineffective in this context.

**P.S:**
While I'm aware I can create separate files for each test scenario, I'm specifically interested in understanding how to handle this within the same file.

Answer (score 0):

Your tests seem like a good candidate for parameterization.

```
class AzureTest {

  @ParameterizedTest
  @MethodSource
  public void testItWorks(Clock clock) {
    Instant instant = clock.instant();
    LocalDate date = instant.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDate();
    System.out.println("======" + date + "======");
    //additional setup
    //actions
    //assertions
  }

  private static List<Clock> testItWorks() {
    return List.of(
            Clock.fixed(LocalDate.of(1800, 10, 10).atStartOfDay().toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC), ZoneOffset.UTC),
            Clock.fixed(LocalDate.of(1900, 10, 10).atStartOfDay().toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC), ZoneOffset.UTC)
    );
  }
}
```

Judging by the imports, you are using junit5, so this example uses parameterization with method parameters. `@MethodSource` provides the parameters from the specified *static* factory method, if a method name is not specified in the annotation, it defaults to a factory method with the same name as the test.